# Error saving dump. Invalid pointer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I am debugging a simple Hello World application created in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It is a .NET Universal Application and does not have an issue.

I simply hit the Break (Pause) button in Visual Studio while the application is idle and then go to `Debug | Save dump as ...` and try to save a dump with the default settings (*Minidump with heap*).

However, I get the following error message:

> Error saving dump. Invalid pointer.

[image: Error saving dump. Invalid pointer.]

Saving the dump without heap information works, but for a .NET application to analyze, I should have the heap.

Version details:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, 14.0.23107.0
- Windows 10 Professional Insider x86, 10.0.10240
- Windows 10 IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to happen sporadically only. Trying it again created the dump.